# How to add a second UITabBar (Controller?) to a UIView in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

So I'm working on an app that has a tab bar for the main part of the app. In the first tab you have a list, and when you tab on a cell it pushed a UIViewController with some details.

This view controller calls (below) when it is created so it hides the tab bar for the main part of the app when it is pushed...

```
[self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
```

I'd like to now add another tab bar to help separate out the information in this pushed details view.

How can I do this? Thanks already! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add a tabbarcontroller to your xib and either add the tabbarcontroller as subview when the detailview appears ( in `viewWillAppear:animated` method ) or directly push the tabbarcontroller as detailview.

Comment: Oh great! I didn't realise it was that simple! :-)